# Does anyone have suggestions on where i can get a VHDL implementation of any Elliptical Curve algorithm?

Tags: cryptography, hardware, hardware-wallets

I know the EC is an old algorithm, but it seems I cant find the algorithm in VHDL. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: checked opencores already? if it isn't there , then you would have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, seems I will have to do it myself, thanks.